# Pandas dtypes dictionary from yaml

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, yaml

I am having an issue where I want to load a section from a YAML file to populate the pandas.read_csv dtypes parameter.  My problem is that the value in the dictionary has ' ' around it and pandas is not recognizing it as a datatype.

```
Yaml:
  dict: {ITEM_GROUP: object, ITEM: object}

import pandas as pd
with open(yaml_org_path, 'r') as f:
    config = yaml.load(f)
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtypes= config['Yaml']['dict'])
```

If I print this part of the YAML file I get:

```
print(config['Yaml']['dict'])
```

{'ITEM_GROUP': 'object', 'ITEM': 'object'}

I am not sure if I am using the dictionary correctly in the Yaml file, or if I need to use some of the pyyaml magic keywords.  I am a novice and am stuck, so thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. Your problem seems to be the parameter `dtypes` in `pd.read_csv` which should be `dtype`:

---

```
import yaml

from io import StringIO
config = yaml.load(StringIO("""
Yaml:
  dict: {ITEM_GROUP: object, ITEM: object}
"""))

config['Yaml']['dict']
# {'ITEM': 'object', 'ITEM_GROUP': 'object'}

pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
ITEM,ITEM_GROUP
a,b
c,d
"""), dtype=config['Yaml']['dict']).dtypes
#     ^^^^^
#ITEM          object
#ITEM_GROUP    object
#dtype: object
```